# In flutter when I am trying to run project it is giving error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Pease help me!, I am new to flutter I am importing a project and when I try to run it is giving exception

/simple_permissions-0.1.9/android/src/main/java/com/ethras/simplepermissions/SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ActivityCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app

My project is already compatible with androidX, I have tried package get and upgrade package but nothing happens, I have got the similar problem

Comment: change your import statement into like this "androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity"

Answer (score 7):

When you migrate a flutter app to AndroidX, all the plugins the app depends on should also support AndroidX else your app build will fail and this is what is happening here.

Even though you have migrated your project to AndroidX, the `simple-permissions` plugin has not been migrated to AndroidX yet and this is what is causing the issue.

Below are the options you have in this case -

**1. User the `permission_handler` plugin instead of `simple-permissions`.**

The `permission_handler` plugin is a much more frequently updated plugin which has already been migrated to AndroidX. Here is the [link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler#-readme-tab-) to the plugin.

**2. Migrate `simple-permissions` to AndroidX yourself**

If you strictly want to use `simple-permissions`, you can clone the git repo and manually migrate the plugin to AndroidX and use the plugin via git url inside your `pubspec.yaml`. Details for migrating plugins to AndroidX can be found [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility).

You can use the plugin from git url in the following way inside you `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  plugin1:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugin1.git 
     //Your repo url goes in place of this url
```

**3. Avoid using AndroidX altogether in you app.**

You can force your app to use the older support libraries if you do not wish to perform the above two steps, but by doing this you will need to downgrade all your plugins to versions which do not use AndroidX, which is not the ideal solution.
More about this [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility).

Hope this helps!